# Adding and saving fields in a related belongsToMany table

Tags: laravel

The tables `category`, `category_description` and `descriptions` are related:

```
public function descriptions(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Description::class);

}
```

```
public function categories(): BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

public function descriptions(): BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(Description::class);
}
```

```
public function descriptions(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);

    }
```

in Model respectively. When saving or updating:

```
public function createOrUpdate(Category $category, Request $request)
    {
        $category->fill($request->get('category'))->save();

        $category->descriptions()->syncWithoutDetaching(
            $request->input('category.descriptions', [])
        );
    }
```

An error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `category_description` (`category_id`, `description`, `description_id`, `is_active`, `meta-description`, `meta-h1`, `meta-keyword`, `meta-title`, `name`, `slug`) values (1, 41231231, 0, 1, 23, 124, 12, 12, 12333312, 74))
```

Perhaps I missed something somewhere, since there is not so much experience.

### UPDATE:

a category can have multiple entries, but the description has only one parent. Rewrote — One To Many (Polymorphic):

```
public function descriptions()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Description::class, 'descriptable');
    }
```

```
public function descriptable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

There are no problems with saving 1 record, but how to update several records at the same time?

Comment: can you `dd('$request->input('category.descriptions')` .... and what is the columns of category_description ?

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▶
    "name" => "12333312"
    "description" => "41231231"
    "meta-title" => "12"
    "meta-description" => "23"
    "meta-keyword" => "12"
    "meta-h1" => "124"
    "slug" => "74"
    "is_active" => "1"
  ]
]

Comment: how about the columns of category_description?

Comment: $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('description_id');
            $table->foreign('description_id')->references('id')->on('descriptions');

Comment: data is displayed about page load, but not saved

Comment: added a description

Comment: if the description has only one category why you need many-to-many ?

Comment: Similar to what @omaresmaeel said, I believe it's now clear that you need a _"one-to-many"_ relationship instead. What doesn't make sense to me is why you rewrote/went for a [_one-to-many(Polymorphic)_](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations) instead of a regular [_one-to-many_](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship.

Comment: Because the description can be used by other tables as well, such as the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about?

```php
// Category Model.

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function descriptions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Description::class)
            ->using(CategoryDescription::class);
    }
}
```

```php
// Description Model.

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Description extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        "name",
        "description",
        "meta-title",
        "meta-description",
        "meta-keyword",
        "meta-h1",
        "slug",
        "is_active",
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
            ->using(CategoryDescription::class);
    }
}
```

```php
// Intermediate Model.

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CategoryDescription extends Pivot
{

    protected $table = "category_description";
    public $incrementing = true;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, "category_id", "id");
    }

    public function description()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Description::class, "description_id", "id");
    }
}
```

```php
// createOrUpdate method.

public function createOrUpdate(Category $category, Request $request)
{
    $category->fill($request->get('category'))->save();

    $description = Description::create(
        Arr::collapse($request->input('category.descriptions', []))
    );

    $category->descriptions()->syncWithoutDetaching(
        $description->id
    );
}
```

### Notes:

Much as this may work for you, I personally think that you don't have a many-to-many relationship here. I believe a one-to-many relationship is sufficient.

Comment: Alert:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `category_description` (`description_id`, `category_id`, `name`, `description`, `meta-title`, `meta-description`, `meta-keyword`, `meta-h1`, `slug`, `is_active`) values (0, 1, 12333312, 41231231, 12ччс, 23, 12, 124, 74, 1))

Comment: @llya Kozlov , Please check out my edited answer.

Comment: Rewrote — One To Many (Polymorphic). 
It helped! But now there are empty fields in the matrix on page load, although everything is OK in the database. Then I will deal with the output of data on the page

Comment: @IlyaKozlov , Just to clarify. Can a specific `category` belong to multiple descriptions?. Secondly, Can a specific `description` belong to multiple categories?. If both answers are _yes_, then a many-to-many relationship would sound reasonable. Let me know about your particular use case.

Comment: @IlyaKozlov, Also [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67752557/edit) and let us know how you're retrieving the data from the database. Lastly, What do you mean when you say _"But now there are empty fields in the matrix on page load"_?.

Comment: $description = Description::create(
        Arr::collapse($request->input('category.descriptions', []))
    );
how to sync records?

Comment: @IlyaKozlov , Did you get your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I figured out the relations and where which ones are better to use

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you send data to be inserted in columns that are not found

You should send only the data that you need to insert in the table

so in your case, you should write your function as

```
$category->descriptions()->syncWithoutDetaching($description_id); // the id of the description you want to attach with this category
```

If you still don't have the description yet in the database and you are creating it with the same request you can do something like this

```
Description::create(['columnName'=>$request->get('columnName'),'columnName2'=>$request->get('columnName2')])->id
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but:
$description_id = Arr::collapse($request->input('category.descriptions', []));
$category->descriptions()->syncWithoutDetaching($description_id);
OUT:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vitabrava_orchid`.`category_description`, CONSTRAINT `category_description_description_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`description_id`) REFERENCES `descriptions` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `category_description` (`description_id`, `category_id`) values (12333312, 1))

Comment: `$description_id` should be something like that `Description::first()->id` ....... it should be the value of the id of the description you want to attach to the category